# how to show data in a datagrid ? (not from database)

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

i want to show some values in a data Grid and these values are not from database.
I am making a POS in which when user enters an item it should be shown to him/her in a data grid form.

Comment: So what is the question? What have you tried and what isn't working - we need that in order to help you solve the problem

Comment: thanks but i've got the soluton :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i've tried and my mistake was i didn't bind the "Name","Price" but now i've correct it and now it works perfectly

```
public struct MyData
{
    public int Price { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataGridTextColumn grid_C1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    DataGridTextColumn grid_C2 = new DataGridTextColumn();

    dGrid.Columns.Add(grid_C1);
    dGrid.Columns.Add(grid_C2);

    grid_C1.Binding = new Binding("Name");
    grid_C2.Binding = new Binding("Price");

    grid_C1.Header = "Name";
    grid_C2.Header = "Price";

    dGrid.Items.Add(new MyData { Name = "dumyText", Price = 2 });
    dGrid.Items.Add(new MyData { Name = "dumyText", Price = 2 });
}
```